# what's the actual screen resolution of mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

I recently started to step in responsive design. I used http://responsivepx.com/ to test how my design will look on every screen resolution. I have a mobile phone (galaxy prime core) which according to that [site](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_core_prime-6716.php) it's 480X800 screen resolution. The thing is, I tried to set a breakpoint on (min-width=480) px but my phone didn't respond to that breakpoint. After further testing, the phone responded to the breakpoint when I set (min-width=320px) it didn't respond when I set it (min-width:321px) so I figured my phone's actual width was 320 in pixels ... 
my question is : what does that mean and is there a way to calculate it or is it just   width - 160 ?

Comment: If you want your design to be responsive and fit all devices, you can use bootstrap for that. It's mobile first so you won't need to worry about resolutions there. Using bootstrap for designing will make your pages responsive to any screen size.

Comment: well that's wasn't my question, but bootstrap is just too heavy for one-page sites ...<div><div><div><div>bootstrap</div></div></div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device width (value your browser sees and you use in media queries) is not `"width - 160"`, it is `"physical width / device pixel density"`.  Your phone's is **150%**, so it is `480 / 1.5 = 320`.

For nice overview of common screen resolutions of mobile phones I'd suggest http://screensiz.es/phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a list of the most commom devices on the internet. I don't think you can do it for ALL the mobiles (there are thousands) but a lot of resolutions are the same. here is a website with some info (in spanish): https://norfipc.com/celulares/medidas-pantalla-resolucion-telefonos-celulares-tabletas.html

and here is a picture with others: http://www.destacaimagen.com/wp-content/uploads/responsive-web-design-chart1.jpg